# Losing instance variable values

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
.h
   @interface sample : NSObject{
    @public
    NSData* data;
    int val;
  }
```

.m

```
@implementation sample

-(id) init:(NSData*)data{
 if (self = [super init]) {
    [self initdata:data];
    }
    NSLog(@"@@@ self %@",self);
    NSLog(@"@@@ self->data %@",self->data);

   return self;
 }
-(void) initdata:(NSData*) data{
 @try{
  self->data = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:data];
     self->val = 10;
 }@catch (NSException* e) {

    }
  }
}
```

after returning from initdata method if i print values it's null.
**When i install app from xcode to iphone everything works fine but when i install using testflight or itunes all the instance variables are null.**

it looks simple, i tried but not able to solve.

Edit:

```
.m
-(id) init:(NSData*)data{
if (self = [super init]) {
    [self initDecodeOffline:data];
}
NSLog(@"@@@ VSF self %@",self);
NSLog(@"@@@ VSF self->SBI %@",self->SBI);

return self;
}
-(void) initDecodeOffline:(NSData*) data{
    @try{
  self->SBI = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:SBI];
        NSLog(@"@@@ VSF SBI-->%@",self->SBI);
    }@catch (NSException* e) {
    self->inErrorState = true;
   }
}
.h
@interface BarCodeProduct : NSObject{
  @public
 int selectedQuantity;
 long rmsCartIndex;
     int referenceId;
     NSData* SBI;
     int maxAllowed;
}
-(id) init:(NSData*)data;
@end
```

Comment: Errr, you are not following conventional naming of those methods. Plus you are doing things in a strange way.  Not sure that's the issue here, but it's very ugly.

Comment: i have changed my class name and variable to post here. ya this is ugly but i am not understanding why its null when installed from testflight.

Comment: Why have you changed them?  Please show us what the actual code looks like.

Comment: @trojanfoe actual code is added in edit section.

Comment: This looks dodgy: `self->SBI = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:SBI];`.

Comment: @trojanfoe in that case local one i changed it to _SBI. still same.

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be `self->SBI = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:data];`, given `data` is passed into the method?

Comment: @trojanfoe for that also getting null, even if am assigning some constatnt value getting null when installing from testflight but working fine when installed directly from xcode.